# Build failed after installing React Native Firebase

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I ran through this guide:

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-react-native-firebase

And the Managed Workflow section of this guide:

https://rnfirebase.io/#managed-workflow

In order to set up Firebase in my Expo project.

But when I run the project with either `npx expo run:ios` or `npx expo run:ios -d`, I get this error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ EXDevLauncher (in
target 'expo-dev-launcher' from project 'Pods')
```

Restarting my Mac did nothing.